# Custom Glide.load()

Tags: android, kotlin, android-glide

The basic use of Glide is like this

```
Glide
    .with(this)
    .load(url)
    .centerCrop()
    .into(binding.imageView)
```

What I want to do is adding query to url based on the width and height of imageView.
My idea is

```
Glide
    .with(this)
    .customLoad(builder, binding.imageView)
    .centerCrop()
    .into(binding.imageView)
```

builder is what I use for creating new Url. It has base url information.

So I tried to custom .load() like this

```
fun RequestManager.customLoad(builder: MyImageClient.Builder, imageView: ImageView):RequestBuilder<Drawable>  {
    if (ViewCompat.isLaidOut(imageView) && !imageView.isLayoutRequested) {
        val width = imageView.width
        val height = imageView.height
        builder.setImageSize(width = width, height = height)
    } else {
        imageView.addOnLayoutChangeListener(object : View.OnLayoutChangeListener {
            override fun onLayoutChange(
                view: View,
                left: Int,
                top: Int,
                right: Int,
                bottom: Int,
                oldLeft: Int,
                oldTop: Int,
                oldRight: Int,
                oldBottom: Int
            ) {
                view.removeOnLayoutChangeListener(this)
                val width = imageView.width
                val height = imageView.height
                builder.setImageSize(width = width, height = height)
            }
        })
    }
    val url = builder.build().createImageUrl()
    return load(url)
}
```

but when imageView isLayoutRequested==true, width and height can't be calculated immediately.
We have to wait until onLayoutChange is called.
How can I wait return load(url) until onLayoutChange() executed and get width and height?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do the fetch until you know the size of the view, so execute the *Glide* statement from *onLayoutChange()* listener instead of burying the change listener in the *Glide* code.

```
binding.imageView.doOnNextLayout {
    // Make adjustments to the URL
    Glide
        .with(this)
        .load(url)
        .centerCrop()
        .into(binding.imageView)
}
```